# Espresso Test Failed: Wanted to match 1 intent, Actually matched 2 intents

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am getting this error while testing activity launch using espresso.

**android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 2 intents.**

Surprisingly other activity launch tests with same code are getting passed.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class HomeActivityTest {

  @Rule
  public final IntentsTestRule<HomeActivity> mHomeActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<HomeActivity>(HomeActivity.class);


  @Test
  public void testFundTransferActivityStarted() {

    onView(withId(R.id.button_fund_transfer)).perform(click());

    intended(hasComponent("mypackage.FundTransferActivity"));
 }

}
```

button click simply starts FundTransfer activity using startActivity.

Comment: You need to add one more argument like in this example `intended(allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL), hasData(INTENT_DATA_PHONE_NUMBER)));
}`

Comment: @piotrek1543 Haven't tried. But Why do I need to add allOf ? Why is it matching two intents instead of one?

Comment: Well, first of all, I have no experience with `espresso-intents`.  But after using standard `espresso` library, I know if something is doubled, you need to make it more specific. `allOf` is like logic AND, where `anyOf` is like OR. These are Hamcrest matchers.

Comment: I face the same problem. Any answers found?

Answer (score 18):

Could you paste the full error message you got?

The error message would have the configuration of the 2 Intents matched as well. If both those intents have the same configuration, that means that you are calling `startActivity` twice, i.e, between test started and test ended. **The below answer is for a specific case when you end up calling the same Intent twice.**

Calling twice is a perfectly legitimate case. For instance,

**Step 1**: tap on `Button1` to launch Gallery and pick a image and show in `ImageView1` (initially `ImageView1` is `GONE` and now it's `VISIBLE`). 
**Step 2**: tap on `ImageView1` to launch the Gallery again.

Now, If you wanted to test "Tapping on `ImageView1` should launch Gallery", then you can't simply tap on `ImageView1` since it's not visible initially. You need to first tap on `Button1`. If you do this, you need to Launch the Gallery **twice**.

Hence `intended(hasComponent("mypackage.FundTransferActivity"));` won't work. Instead use: **`intended(hasComponent("mypackage.FundTransferActivity"), times(2));`**

Comment: Why is **times(2)** necessary?